# Tiling a $2n-1 \times 2n-1$ board by $L$ triominos, $Z$ tetrominoes and box tetrominoes

Tags: combinatorics, tiling

A $2n-1 \times 2n-1$ board is going to be tiled by L triominoes, Z tetrominoes and Box tetrominoes. Prove
that at least 4n − 1 L triominoes must be used.

Any ideas how can I solve this? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colour the cells of every other row of the board alternating blue and red. Cover the cells of the remaining rows alternating green and yellow (such that the first column is alternating blue and green). Then each tetromino covers one cell of each colour, while the triomino covers three different colours.

How many cells are there of each? There will be $n^2$ blue, $n(n-1)$ red and green, and $(n-1)^2$ yellow cells. To make up for this discrepancy, you need $2n-1$ triominoes that don't cover yellow, $n$ that don't cover red and $n$ that don't cover green.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on the discrepancy? From what I understand, it is like removing $2n-1$ from $(n-1)^2$ is $n^2$. and removing $n$ from green and red gives $n^2$. So every color is $n^2$ times. But why do you need $2n-1$ triominos that don't cover yellow and so on? I don't fully understand.

Comment: @funbiggun For instance, for $n=4$, we have a $7\times7$ board. There will be $16$ blue squares, $12$ red and green, and $9$ yellow. If you have $7$ triominoes that don't cover yellow (and therefore each cover a blue, a red and a green cell), $4$ that don't cover green and $4$ that don't cover red, you will have covered $15$ blue, $11$ red, $11$ green and $8$ yellow, so there is one cell of each colour left. Since the number of remaining cells in each colour is equal, the rest can now be done with tetrominoes (or really a single tetromino).

Comment: Cool!, Thank you very much. But I have two questions. 1) How are you sure that this indeed is the minimum number of triominos needed. Why can't I get a tiling where less triominos are used and tiled successfully? 2) After tiling with triominos, for instance even in this case, how can you be sure that the remaining 4 cells are like in a shape that can be tileable with a box or z tetromino? What if one cell is one side of the square and the other is on the other side, meaning the cells are not adjacent so that it is tileable? What is the prove that it won't happen?

Comment: @funbiggun 1) There are $2n-1$ too many blue, $n$ too many red and $n$ too many green cells (compared to yellow cells) for you to cover the board with tetrominoes. Each triomino can correct the discrepancy between the number of cells by 1. So you need $4n-1$ of these corrections. 2) Completely irrelevant. We are not asked to show that it can be done by using exactly $4n-1$ tetrominoes. We are asked to show that we can't use fewer.